Google Calendar API, the holidays calendar throws sync token is no longer valid
I have an issue. I have a calendar application. In general, everything is working and syncing as expected, but the Google managed "Holidays in X" calendar is giving me a sync issue.
It returns the nextPageToken and nextSyncTokens as expected, ie. I can

Fetch 100 records at a time, getting a nextPageToken
at the end of the records, it sends nextPageToken = null and gives me a nextSyncToken

But when I fetch data with the next sync token, then it gives me an error.
"Error: Sync token is no longer valid, a full sync is required."
Granted, I make the request right away, fully expecting that nothing has changed. But every other calendar will just respond with an empty list of items and the same sync token in this case, even the Google managed addressbook calendar for the same parent user.
Is this normal? What am I missing? - Why is this single calendar giving me an error on a seemingly valid nextSyncToken.
PS. The nextSyncToken I get at the end is always the same when testing, atleast in the current small timeframe of 2 days, so it hasn't changed.

Syncing the holiday calendar seems more or less completely meaningsless. I don't know this for a fact, but I would guess they have just made a special case for that.

The holidays calendars change every so often, maybe after a few years I'd think, so it ain't completely meaningless.
Nevertheless, you might be correct, but I'd still like some confirmation from anywhere that this is the case.

So you're going to hold on to a sync-token for a couple of years? At that point making a new full fetch is probably a better idea, no? (That's what I do. Have an app that syncs with google calendar.)

Why not hold onto a sync token for a couple of years? I don't see any issues with it.
Also, all systems should ideally have no exceptions, so I would like for holiday calendars to function like any other calendars.

The issue would be that it is much less fault tolerant, and the upside is none. You can't expect a server to be stable for several years. Tokens could get invalidated. Even when things are seamingly working as it should, to not have an "escape hatch" of wiping all the data and making a new full sync would be a mistake. And the gain would be... to avoid a handful of requests every year?

I have an escape hatch, the resync is fully functional, that's not the issue. The issue is that this one (or more) calendar acts differently than others and I want to know why.

I think the issue is more that you're moving the goal post... :) But anyhow, I digress. If you're just out to satisfy your curiosity I can't be of much help.

It's literally necessary to know the nuances of the core systems you are working with. Thanks anyway.
